# Split multiple Words in a string

Tags: regex, string

I have a String like this

```
String s1="1 AND 1 OR 1";
```

I want split with AND OR and my result should be 1,1,1

I am using JAVA /eclipse 
package com.test;

String s1="1 AND 1 OR 1";

String[] splits=s1.split("[AND\OR]");

for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {

System.out.println(splits[i]);

}

}

}

Can I get any help how to do this?

Any Help appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regular expressions, totally language specific, and doesn't specify the mandatory complementary tag

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) - Scroll to *other* and see `\s`

Comment: Which language/tool are you using for your regex?

Comment: I am using JAVA /eclipse 
package com.test;

public class tesdt {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 /*String str="1 AND 1";
 int[] my=new int[100];
 String[] s= str.split("AND");
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  my[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i].trim());
  
 }*/
 
 
 String s1="1 AND 1 OR 1";

 String[] splits=s1.split("[AND\\OR]");
 for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(splits[i]);

 }
}
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am unsure about the language, but for `C#` you can use the following:

```
string s1 = "1 AND 1 OR 1";
string s2 = s1.Replace("AND", ",").Replace("OR", ",");
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Which doesn't use regular expressions.

If you want an array, you can use the following:

```
string s1 = "1 AND 1 OR 1";
string[] s2 = Regex.Split(s1.Replace(" ", string.Empty), "AND|OR");
```

---

In `Java` you can replace using the same mechanism:

```
String s1 = "1 AND 1 OR 1";
String s2 = s1.replace("AND", ",").replace("OR", ",");
System.out.println(s2);
```

And to get an array:

```
String s1="1 AND 1 OR 1";
String[] s2 = s1.replace(" ", "").split("AND|OR");
```

Comment: S?he wants to split, basically s?he expects an array

Comment: I think that depends on how you interpret the question. There is no actual use of the word `Array`...

Comment: if I have the string as :- 
String s1="(1 AND 1) OR 1";

Then how to resolve?

Comment: .replace("(", "").replace(")", "");